# bind key to negative-argument + command in emacs

Tags: emacs, initialization, elisp, key-bindings

I am trying to bind to M-b a command preceded by a negative argument. I post my code.

working

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-f"))                                                         
(global-set-key (kbd "M-f") 'forward-whitespace)
```

not working

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "M-b"))                                                         
(global-set-key (kbd "M-b") (lambda () (interactive) (negative-argument(forward-whitespace))))
```

How can I make it working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specific issue you have is solved easily:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-b") (lambda () (interactive) (forward-whitespace -1)))
```

You might wonder if you can write a macro that would call an arbitrary command interactively with negative argument.

It is not really hard:

```
(defmacro call-with-negative-argument (command)
  `(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (prefix-command-preserve-state)
     (setq prefix-arg '-)
     (universal-argument--mode)
     (call-interactively ,command)))
(global-set-key (kbd "...") (call-with-negative-argument forward-whitespace))
```

but, really, any *compliant* function would also work fine like this:

```
(defmacro call-with-negative-argument (command)
  `(lambda ()
     (interactive)
     (,command -1)))
```

Comment: thank you! Regarding this answer I have unfortunately another question: please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024130/tell-emacs-to-interpret-words-breaking-them-at-newline-and-whitespace