# Tell emacs to interpret words breaking them at newline and whitespace

Tags: emacs, elisp, key-bindings

I would like to tell emacs to break "words" when there is a whitespace or a newline (the one used in forward-word).

If I use forward-word on this (the cursor is in the capital letter or with a _)

```
_aaaa} {bbbb
```

then I get

```
aaaa} {bbbb_
```

Since I dislike this behaviour I tried remapping M-f with forward-whitespace. In the above case the cursors places between the two brackets, as I want, but in a case like this

```
_aaaa-bbbb
```

the cursor goes here after a forward-whitespace

```
aaaa-bbbb_
```

so if I want to go to the beginning of the word bbbb I have to use forward-word.

> How can I tell emacs to break "words" all the whitespace (a block of
>   whitespace should be interpreted as a single whitespace, just like
>   forward-whitespace does), and also to break words when changing line?

For the moment I use M-f for forward-word and M-F for forward-whitespace, but this is awkward.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `M-f` does not skip whitespace.

Comment: you are right but try it with this aaaa} {bbbb. In this case it does not work.

Comment: it does work for me. first it take me to after the last `a`, then to after the last `b`. you should examine you syntax table,

Comment: As noted by sds, this depends on syntax tables, which in turn depend on the major mode.  So you have to specify the major mode/syntax table you're using.  Also, you may want to look at my `syntax-subword` package (in melpa), which provides functions to move by syntax boundary (and also CamelCase), which is more fine grained than word movement.

Comment: @jpkotta How can I modify the syntax table for a specified major mode?

Comment: @LucaMarconato `describe-syntax` will show you the current syntax table(s), but won't show the name.  Usually the table is named after the major mode, e.g. `foo-mode-syntax-table`.  Use `modify-syntax-entry` to change a table, and `with-syntax-table` to change it temporarily.  You can see what syntax a given character is with `describe-char`.